# Selenium Chromedriver Crash on service_args in Constructor

Tags: python, macos, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running chromedriver 90 using python 3.7.4 on MacOS.  I'm geting an exception constructing the webdriver.Chrome instance when I try passing "" (empty string - should mean all addresses) for service_args `--allowed-ips`. This is the error I'm getting:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1`

chromedriver is allowed in my Mac Firewall settings for allowing incoming connections.  Any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: is import is successfully done for the webdriver in your IDE ?
`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")`

Comment: Yes, the import succeeds. Constructing the driver instance fails and crashes the executable.